# java regex replace all to get hostname

Tags: java, regex

I have the following url :

```
https://mydemo.company/pages/pag1
```

I want get mydemo from url string,
Can we have the regex that can be used in **replaceAll** to negate everything else and get mydemo

```
 replaceAll('regextoNegate','')
```

Comment: Use `str = str.replaceAll("^http://|\\..+$", "");`

Comment: Please Use `.*?\/\/(.*?)\..*`. See  https://regex101.com/r/NNrrTE/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple alternation based regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^https?://|\\..+$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4LV7EZ/1)

There are 2 alternations:

- `^https?://`: Match starting `http://` or `https://`
- `|`: OR
- `\\..+$`: Match substring starting from first dot to end

Replacement is just an empty string.

Comment: Thanks... I got the answer from regex champion :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
.*?\/\/(.*)\..*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.*?\/\/`** - Matches everything lazily before `//`.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents first capturing group matching everything after the `//` and before the last `.` since it is a greedy match.
- **`\.`** - Matches `.` literally.
- **`.*`** - Matches everything after `.` zero or more time.
- **`$1`** - Represents the first captured group.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the sample implementation of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/NNrrTE/1)

**Sample implementation in java:**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "https://mydemo.company/pages/pag1\nhttps://mydemo.secondString.company/pages/pag1";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*?\\/\\/(.*)\\..*", "$1"));
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/H1NQMHDC8)

Comment: You were close. Use `.*?\\/\\/([^\\.]*).*` as the regex and update your answer after testing it.